# Problems with audio in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, shutdown

After installing updates and rebooting, I have some problems with 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 running kernel version 3.5.0-34-generic.

The most obvious problem is that audio does not work but there are other problems such as the reboot menu on the Ubuntu (Unity?) login screen does not work (I can click on it and a very small empty popup window appears) and when rebooting, the machine gets stuck in the shutdown screen (I'm using the xubuntu-desktop package, so the shutdown screen says "Xubuntu").

Logging into Xubuntu works fine except for the missing sound.
When logging into Unity, the system menu at the top right has the same problem as on the login screen (empty, very small).

The output of dmesg contains notes on found audio hardware (see blow) and `hwinfo --sound` also gives me information about found hardware but also contains an error message (see below).

Where to look next to pin the problem down and find a resolution?

Thanks!

Relevant `dmesg` output.

```
[   13.067650] hda-intel: 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
...
[   13.952341] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input9
[   13.952459] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input10
[   13.952562] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
[   13.952659] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
```

Output of  `hwinfo --sound`.

```
$ hwinfo --sound
> hal.1: read hal dataprocess 2669: arguments to dbus_move_error() were incorrect, assertion "(dest) == NULL || !dbus_error_is_set ((dest))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-errors.c line 282.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
libhal.c 3483 : Error unsubscribing to signals, error=The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
14: PCI 1b.0: 0403 Audio device                                 
  [Created at pci.318]
  Unique ID: u1Nb.59eWIJiira0
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:1b.0
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "Intel Audio device"
  Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x1c20 
  SubVendor: pci 0x1028 "Dell"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0498 
  Revision: 0x04
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xd8b60000-0xd8b63fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 45 (245 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00001C20sv00001028sd00000498bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

23: PCI 100.1: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.318]
  Unique ID: NXNs.ukALa87MFX5
  Parent ID: vSkL.xBHHillLvg6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.1
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "nVidia Audio device"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x0be3 
  SubVendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0862 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xd8080000-0xd8083fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 17 (7644 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd00000BE3sv000010DEsd00000862bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #9 (PCI bridge)
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had similar problems trying to use HDMI to access builtin monitor speakers.  A simple work-a-round was to unplug/re-plug in the HDMI cable after rebooting. 
this somehow caused the speakers to then be acknowledged.  You may also try configuring System Settings ==> Sound ==> Output.